# Storing HTML source code in python variable

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Here is the code I'm using :

```
import urllib2
import psycopg2

add = 'http://google.com'
res = urllib2.urlopen(add)
url_html = res.read()
con = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres',password='test_pwd',host='localhost',port=5432,database='test_db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO output(output) values ('%r')" %(url_html))
#cur.execute("INSERT INTO output(output) values ('''%s''')" %(url_html))
con.commit()
```

Now its throwing an error because of ' ' as quotes are inside the page's source code too.
Can anybody help me out with this.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always escape database input, even if you're just downloading HTML from a web page, or you're making yourself vulnerable to SQL Injection. What if someone puts a `drop table` command in the HTML? You might end up executing it. Also, in your case escaping will actually solve your problem.

In `psycopg2` you can escape parameters like this:

`cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)", (100, "abc'def"))`
(shamelessly stolen from http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html)

Read more about SQL Injection: [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: make a single item tuple in Python you need a comma otherwise solution was perfect {cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)", (100, "abc'def",))}

Comment: In my example the tuple has two values, so no additional comma is needed. There already is one between the two values. But in your own case you would indeed need a comma.

Comment: Right their you are my bad , Also I'm aware of the consequences it is for R&D purpose. Thanks for your help